# SQL Calculating the subscription rate based on entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dataset

I am given a list of data shown as the following:

| user_id | created_at | sign_up_at | platform |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:01:01 | NULL | ios |
| 2 | 2021-01-10 07:13:42 | 2021-01-11 08:00:00 | web |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 12:11:44 | 2021-02-01 13:11:44 | android |
| 4 | 2021-02-28 04:32:12 | 2021-02-28 05:32:12 | ios |
| 5 | 2021-03-22 01:12:11 | 2021-03-22 02:12:11 | android |

(name of dataset) users

I'm supposed to extract the number of subscribers and the subscription rate. I have managed to extract the number of subscribers but I am confused on how to extract the subscription rate, since it is tracked by either NULL or a date. I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT sign_up_at  COUNT(*) * 100.0/sum(count(*))Over() as subscription_rate 
FROM users
```

However, I know the code is incorrect because I am not identifying whether or not each user is NULL or not. How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you give a definition of the subscription rate?

Comment: The number of users who signed up! In this case, 4 out of 5 people have signed up so the subscription rate would be 4/5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count function counts only the not null values, so `COUNT(sign_up_at)` will count the number of users where 'sign_up_at' is not null. `COUNT(*)` will count all the rows in the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(sign_up_at) / COUNT(*) * 100.0 AS subscription_rate 
FROM users
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E-6RPrKQ).